# How to access auth response in trigger file

Tags: php, command-line-interface, zapier

When a user tries to connect my Zapier app, I'll ask for a login. I have used custom authentication, you can see the code below.

```
const testAuth = (z , bundle) => 
   {
    var email = bundle.authData.email;
    var password = bundle.authData.password;
    return z.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://mysite/check_login',
     }).then((response) => {
     if (response['status'] === 201) {
       throw new Error('Your credentials is not match with our database');
     }
     else
     {
       var obj = JSON.parse( response.content );
       var  user_id =obj.user_id;
       return user_id;
     }
   });
```

This is run successfully, now I want to use this return data `user_id` in 
trigger `page(list.js)` code listed below,

```
const list = (z, bundle) => {
 //I WANTS TO USE THAT USER_ID OVER HERE
 //USER_ID=;
 const promise = z.request('http://mysite/list_data/'+USER_ID,
 {
   params: {} 
 });
 return promise.then((response) => response.json);
};
```

Please help me out how to access auth response in trigger file.

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic dropdown field for a trigger like below screnshot

[image: this]

to access user_id in a perform API call.

Here is an example app that utilizing dynamic dropdown feature:

https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-example-app-dynamic-dropdown

More helpful articles:

1. https://platform.zapier.com/cli_tutorials/dynamic-dropdowns
2. https://platform.zapier.com/cli_docs/docs#dynamic-dropdowns

Comment: Hey Kishor, Thanks for your reply, my question is not about dynamic dropdown. It is about how to access authentication.js file result in list.js (trigger file).

Comment: if you are using a standard auth mechanism then you can put data to `bundle.authData` and can use into a trigger, search, action, and resources. But since user_id is an API response of testAuth call so as  I know we can't use testAuth api's response into the other trigger, action, search or resources,

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Great question!

Normally, [computed fields](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/tree/master/packages/cli#computed-fields) would be the answer here, but it's not currently possible to use those outside of `OAuth`.

In your case, there are two options:

1. If there's an easy and obvious way for the user to manually supply their id, then add it to the auth fields use it as needed
2. Otherwise, you'll need to call the login endpoint before you run each trigger to fetch the user id. You've got 30 seconds of execution time, so doing a second API request should be doable.

Comment: No explicit examples, but in your `perform` method, make the same request you're making above (`z.requeust` w/ data from `bundle.authData` as params), get the `user_id` from the response, then use it in a second `z.request` to the `list_data` endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time, i solved it using other way.

Comment: can you update your question or post your solution as an answer to help future askers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sure, Rather than sending user_id that is returned by the auth response, in sending bundle.authData.email at the end of the URL.

```
const list = (z, bundle) => {
 var email=encodeURIComponent(bundle.authData.email);//Like this
 const promise = z.request('http://mysite/list_data/'+email,
 {
   params: {} 
 });
 return promise.then((response) => response.json);
```

};